# Find all integer solutions to linear congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions to linear congruences:

\begin{align}
&(a) &3x &\equiv 24 \pmod{6},\\
&(b) &10x  &\equiv 18 \pmod{25},\\
\end{align}

What I have so far:

$$(a) \gcd(3,6)=3$$
And we know $3|24$ so there are $3$ solutions.  By inspection we know that $x=8$ is a solution.

One, question I have is, even though $x=8$ is a solution, I can also see that $x=2$ is a solution, and among others.  Does it matter which I choose, or do I randomly choose a solution I see?  From here I'm a tad confused.  I'm missing something very simple.

$$(b) \gcd (10,25)=5$$

And $5 \nmid 18$ so there are no solutions.  Right?

Comment: There is something wrong here.  In (a), $24$ is a multiple of $6$ which makes the question odd and the answers even.

Comment: Since $\rm\:8\equiv 2\pmod 6$ they are the same solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem), $(10,25)=5$ must divide $9$ to admit any solution, which is not, so there is no solution.

$3x\equiv 24\pmod 6\implies 2\mid x$ i.e., any even value(not only $8$) of $x$ will satisfy the 1st congruence.

So, the system of the linear congruence has no solution as the 2nd congruence is not solvable.

---

Alternatively, for the 2nd congruence, $10x-18=25y$ for some integer $y$,

So,$5(2x-5y)=18, \frac{18}5=2x-5y$ which is an integer, hence contradiction.

Comment: So, for $(a)$ I see: $$\begin{align}
& 3x &\equiv 0 \pmod{6},\\
& 3x  &\equiv 6 \pmod{6},\\
& 3x  &\equiv 12 \pmod{6},\\\end{align}$$ So, $x=0,2,4...$  Are the solutions.  How would I say this on an exam?

Comment: @student.llama, From the 1st line of your comment, $6\mid 3x\implies 2\mid x$

Answer (score 0):

In (a) you say there are three solutions.  In fact you should say there are three, modulo $6$.  These are $0$, $2$ and $4$, and so all even $x$ are solutions to the original expression.

In (b) you are correct.  Clearly $10x$ is always a multiple of $5$ and numbers equivalent to $18 \pmod{ 25}$ never are.